# Como sobrecargar operator int de forma global en C++

Tags: c++

estoy practicando la sobrecarga de operadores en C++, hasta el momento puedo sobrecargar un operador adentro de la clase pero he visto códigos donde puede declarar la sobrecarga de forma global, he probado con el operador + y me funciona de maravilla pero con el operador int solo funciona al definirlo de forma interna en la clase:

```
#include <iostream>


class objeto{
public:
    int valor;
    objeto(int entrada){
        this->valor=entrada;
    }
    //operador resta interno
    objeto operator - (objeto otro){
        return objeto(this->valor-otro.valor);
    }
    //operador int interno
    operator int(){
        return this->valor;
    }
};

//operador suma global
objeto operator+ (objeto primero, objeto segundo){
    return objeto(primero.valor+segundo.valor);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    objeto objeto_1 = objeto(6);
    objeto objeto_2 = objeto(4);
    
    //usando el operador de resta que esta definido de forma interna en la clase
    objeto objeto_3 = objeto_1-objeto_2;
    
    //usando el operador de suma que esta definido de forma global
    objeto objeto_4 = objeto_1+objeto_2;
    
    std::cout << "objeto restados resultado: " << objeto_3.valor << std::endl;
    std::cout << "objeto sumados resultado: " << objeto_4.valor << std::endl;
    
    //usando operador int interno
    std::cout << "operador int resultado: " << static_cast<int>(objeto_1) << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Alguien conoce alguna forma de sobrecargar el operador int de forma global porque el siguiente código no funciona como yo esperaría:

```
operator int (objeto entrada){
    return entrada.valor;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo que tú llamas operador `int` es conocido en [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) como *operador de conversión* y como su (verdadero) nombre indica sirve para decirle al compilador cómo convertir un tipo de dato en otro; en tu caso le dices al compilador cómo un objeto de tipo `objeto` puede ser convertido en un objeto de tipo `int`, por ejemplo:

```
struct S { operator int() { return {}; } };

void f(int) {}

int main()
{
    S s;

    /* Se llama al operador 'int' para convertir la instancia de 'S' en un entero
       para poder guardarlo en 'i1'. La conversión es implícita. */
    int i1 = s;

    /* Se llama al operador 'int' explícitamente para convertir la instancia de 'S'
       en un entero para poder guardarlo en 'i1'. */
    int i2 = static_cast<int>(s);

    /* Se llama al operador 'int' para convertir la instancia de 'S' en un entero
       para poder pasarlo como argumento a la función 'f'. La conversión es implícita. */
    f(s);

    return 0;
}
```

Los operadores sirven para decirle al compilador cómo tratar un operador cuando un tipo de dato aparece a la izquierda o a la derecha de dicho operador, por ejemplo:

```
struct S
{
    S operator+(float) { return {}; };
    S operator+(float) const { return {}; };
};

S operator+(const S &, const std::string &) { return {}; };
S operator+(const std::string &, const S &) { return {}; };

int main()
{
    S s1;
    const S s2;

    s1 + .0f; // Llama a S::operator+(float)
    s2 + .0f; // Llama a S::operator+(float) const porque 's2' es const.
    0.f + s1; // Error, no existe operador + con 'S' a la derecha de un float.
    0.f + s2; // Error, no existe operador + con 'S' a la derecha de un float.

    /* Llama a operator+(const S &, const std::string &) porque 's1' esta a la
       izquierda del operador. */
    s1 + "Hola";

    /* Llama a operator+(const std::string &, const S &) porque 's2' esta a la
       derecha del operador. */
    " mundo!" + s2;

    return 0;
}
```

Los dos tipos de operador (función miembro y función libre, que tú llamas global) se usan en contextos diferentes: en el operador miembro el objeto **siempre** estará a la izquierda del operador y el operador libre permite que el objeto esté a la izquierda o a la derecha del operador.

En resumen, el uso de estos operadores se deduce por contexto:

- Cuando el objeto de un tipo toma el lugar de otro tipo, si existe una conversión se usará esa conversión.
- Cuando el objeto forma parte de una expresión con un operador, si existe el operador se usará el operador.

Y es por eso que no existe un operador de conversión libre (que tú llamas global), mientras que en un operador binario (`+`, `-`, `*`, ...) el objeto puede aparecer a la izquierda o a la derecha del operador, en una conversión de datos sólo puede formar parte de una expresión del lado derecho (RValue).